# How can I display a different layout with bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display a different layout for my mobile views. In the desktop view using the grid system I have 4 columns each with 2 columns an image and a label+value. In mobile I want to skip the image column and for the label and value I want them next to eachother so something like:

This is a label : this is a span.

1 column in the desktop version looks something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <p>col-md-4</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div>This is a label</div>
        <span>This is a span</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use col-sm-3 but it still displays in the desktop? How can I get the mobile view with the label and value next to eachother?

See also:[codepen](http://codepen.io/gekkerkanniet/pen/wzVbGK)

Comment: use media query

Comment: use col-xs-3 it will be useful. For mobile xs class is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use bootstrap css class :

[image]

```
<h2>Example</h2>
<p>Resize this page to see how the text below changes:</p>
<h1 class="visible-xs">This text is shown only on an EXTRA SMALL screen.</h1>
<h1 class="visible-sm">This text is shown only on a SMALL screen.</h1>
<h1 class="visible-md">This text is shown only on a MEDIUM screen.</h1>
<h1 class="visible-lg">This text is shown only on a LARGE screen.</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a media queries you can change the attributes of elements/classes/IDs based on screen size. You may be particularly interested in using `display: none;` as follows:

**CSS**

```
/*For smartphone and small devices*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
   .hide-me { 
        display: none;
    }
}

/*For tablet sized devices and larger*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 748px) {
   .hide-me { 
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Of course you can double up the functionality of `col-xs-3` (or any of your choosing) but using that as your class selector in the media query.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 748px) {
   .col-xs-3 { 
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Check out some standard documentation responsive design - especially those provided by Twitter! Mobile first is common, where you start with the smaller media queries then get bigger.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/